# Regular expression for "|" separated values

Tags: regex

I would like to validate a line like this :

```
Price (sales)||ALL|Table|HOTP3060|General|3000||||B2B|BUC|149.9|RON|0|0|0|18.05.2016|31.12.2099|YES
```

First of all i don't need to be very specific. Just check if the number of vertical bars is correct. As shown above, some of the information between the bars is missing. That's not an error, is just missing, we should go to the next vertical bar and so on.

The error should be noticed if any of the "|" are missing.

One more thing, fields containing 3000, 149.9 should be constrained as decimal numbers.

Pseudocode for this as i'm seeing it:

- any characters or missing | any characters or missing |  .... | dec value or missing |

  - and for the dates the format is fixed : dd.mm.yyyy

I've started with :

```
[a-zA-Z()]+\|\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[a-zA-z]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|
```

but i don't figure out how to mention the fact that some of the info might be missing.

Something like :

- [a-zA-Z()]+  characters or nothing |

  - [a-zA-Z0-9]+\|  characters and numbers or nothing |

OK i got here:

```
 [a-zA-Z()]+\|\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[a-zA-z]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[0-9]+\|\|\|\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[a-zA-Z]+\|\d+(\.\d{1,2})\|[a-zA-Z]+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\|\w+
```

Everything is parsed.. but as it seems, pretty ugly ..

Comment: IMHO, your question does not show research effort. There are [many](http://regexone.com/) places to get a starting point...

Comment: I've started with [a-zA-Z()]+\|\|[a-zA-Z]+\| detecting the first two columns but i can't find out how to point out the "missing" option.

Comment: you should put that into your question :)

Comment: Do you expect a fixed number of "|" in each line?

Comment: Yes, fixed number of "|" and info between may be  missing.

Comment: I've just added what i am trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create patterns for numbers: `\d+(\.\d+)?` and dates: `\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}`. Then, come up with a pattern that matches a single `|`-delimited segment: `[^|]*|`. Then just combine the three patterns as necessary:

```
^                             start of string anchor
([^|]*\|){6}                  match exactly 6 |-delimited segments
(\d+(\.\d+)?)?                match a decimal number or nothing
(\|[^|]*){5}                  match exactly 5 |-delimited segments
\|(\d+(\.\d+)?)?              match a | delimiter and if possible a number
(\|[^|]*){4}                  match 4 |-delimited segments
(\|(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})?){2}   match a | delimiter and if possible a date. Two times.
\|[^|]*                       match one last | segment
$                             end of string anchor, makes sure we've matched the whole string
```

Result:

```
^([^|]*\|){6}(\d+(\.\d+)?)?(\|[^|]*){5}\|(\d+(\.\d+)?)?(\|[^|]*){4}(\|(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})?){2}\|[^|]*$
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. I am trying to digest it though :)